# Android ADB commands to get the device properties

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am trying to get the device properties from ADB commands. I can how ever get those values by running sample android application. How ever I wish to get using adb shell command itself to make my life easier. Here is the way I will get through sample application but I want corresponding adb commands for

1. device manufacturer
2. device hardware
3. device model
4. Os version(integer value)
5. Kernel version

*** Please note my device is not rooted and I have no idea of rooting the device to get these values :-) ***

```
## Code snippet
import android.os.Build;
manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
hardware = Build.HARDWARE;
model = Build.MODEL;
oSVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
kernelVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
```

However I can able to get the os version. But then I want SDK version in integer. I want 18 in place of 4.2.2

```
C:\>adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
4.2.2
```

Comment: A sample output would also be useful here.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```

If you want to see the whole list of parameters just type:

```
adb shell getprop
```

Comment: How do we get that info if we have multiple devices connected?

Comment: You can write an script to execute the same adb command to all the devices or just specify the one that you are interested in with -s

Comment: There's also the adb -d switch, that: directs command to the only connected USB device returns an error if more than one USB device is present. (or -e for emulator)

Comment: Thanks, I used this for `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state` to understand if my huawei p9 lite is full disk encrypted. Hope someone else finds this comment searching with google.

Answer (score 38):

From Linux Terminal:

```
adb shell getprop | grep "model\|version.sdk\|manufacturer\|hardware\|platform\|revision\|serialno\|product.name\|brand"
```

From Windows PowerShell:

```
adb shell 
getprop | grep -e 'model' -e 'version.sdk' -e 'manufacturer' -e 'hardware' -e 'platform' -e 'revision' -e 'serialno' -e 'product.name' -e 'brand'
```

Sample output for Samsung:

```
[gsm.version.baseband]: [G900VVRU2BOE1]
[gsm.version.ril-impl]: [Samsung RIL v3.0]
[net.knoxscep.version]: [2.0.1]
[net.knoxsso.version]: [2.1.1]
[net.knoxvpn.version]: [2.2.0]
[persist.service.bdroid.version]: [4.1]
[ro.board.platform]: [msm8974]
[ro.boot.hardware]: [qcom]
[ro.boot.serialno]: [xxxxxx]
[ro.build.version.all_codenames]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [G900VVRU2BOE1]
[ro.build.version.release]: [5.0]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [21]
[ro.build.version.sdl]: [2101]
[ro.com.google.gmsversion]: [5.0_r2]
[ro.config.timaversion]: [3.0]
[ro.hardware]: [qcom]
[ro.opengles.version]: [196108]
[ro.product.brand]: [Verizon]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [samsung]
[ro.product.model]: [SM-G900V]
[ro.product.name]: [kltevzw]
[ro.revision]: [14]
[ro.serialno]: [e5ce97c7]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `adb shell getprop` command and `grep` specific info about your current device,  For additional information you can read documentation:
[Android Debug Bridge documentation](http://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/)

I added some examples below:

1. language - `adb shell getprop | grep language`

   > [persist.sys.language]: [en]
   >
   > [ro.product.locale.language]: [en]
2. boot complete ( device ready after reset)  - `adb shell getprop | grep boot_completed`

   > [sys.boot_completed]: [1]
3. device model - `adb shell getprop | grep model`

   > [ro.product.model]: [Nexus 4]
4. sdk version  - `adb shell getprop | grep sdk`

   > [ro.build.version.sdk]: [22]
5. time zone - `adb shell getprop | grep timezone`

   > [persist.sys.timezone]: [Asia/China]
6. serial number   - `adb shell getprop | grep serialno`

   > [ro.boot.serialno]: [1234567]

Answer (score 1):

For Power-Shell

```
./adb shell getprop | Select-String -Pattern '(model)|(version.sdk)|(manufacturer)|(platform)|(serialno)|(product.name)|(brand)'
```

For Linux (burrowing answer from @0x8BADF00D)

```
adb shell getprop | grep "model\|version.sdk\|manufacturer\|hardware\|platform\|revision\|serialno\|product.name\|brand"
```

For single string find in power shell

```
./adb shell getprop | Select-String -Pattern 'model'
```

or

```
./adb shell getprop | Select-String -Pattern '(model)'
```

For multiple

```
./adb shell getprop | Select-String -Pattern '(a|b|c|d)'
```