# Fetching device data through ADB on Windows

Tags: adb

If I have Android phone connected via USB, how do I know the commands I can send via USB to get Information like

1. core temperature of the device,
2. version of android,
3. power consumption details, etc.

Can I then use ADB logs, command to interact with Android mobile. Please may i know the process apart from commands if I have to send commands via ADB.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the Android device properties using **`getprop`**  command.

Please go through this [blog](http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/?m=1) .Here I am listing some of the major ADB commands. Feel free to ask doubts regarding these commands.

Comment: Thanks Don but unfortunately the blog link says the blog does not exist. Please can you help me.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful link. I believe we need to install adb to feed the commands. May I ask one question 1. Say I want to continuously report the power, do I have to feed "adb shell 26" ? I see time parameter missing say I want this to be executed every 50 ms. 2. My other question is please tell me the step by step process of feeding same information from windows command prompt. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To get information from an android device, you can always use the following tools.

Use utilities like `dumpsys` or `getprop`.
Query from `/sys/` or `/proc/`.

Eventually all utilities, fetch information from `/proc` or `/sys`, so you can directly investigate into these.

You could use `dumpsys` tools to get information:

1. `Core temperature of the device`
   I'm not sure, what exactly do you mean by `core temperature of the device`.

   1. Temperature of Device:  <sup>Note</sup>

      ```
      $ adb shell cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
      37
      ```
   2. Temperature of Battery:

      ```
       $ adb shell cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/device/power_supply/battery/temp
       285
      ```

      or

      ```
      $ adb shell dumpsys battery                                
      Current Battery Service state:
      AC powered: false
      USB powered: true
      Wireless powered: false
      status: 2
      health: 2
      present: true
      level: 15
      scale: 100
      voltage: 3768
      current now: -357254
      temperature: 285    # <---- Temparature.
      technology: Li-ion
      ```
2. `Version of android`

   ```
   $ getprop ro.build.version.release  
   4.4.4   #<--- Android Kitkat 4.4.4
   ```
3. I'm not completely sure how you can get exact information:
   You could start with,

   ```
   $ adb shell dumpsys power 
   POWER MANAGER (dumpsys power)

   Power Manager State:
           ....
   ```

**Note:** Results on a Linux System.

```
$ acpi -t      # <--- apci power utility/tool.
Thermal 0: ok, 29.8 degrees C
Thermal 1: ok, 27.8 degrees C

$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp 
27800
```

---

`I want this to be executed every 50 ms ?`
You could write a script with above commands, that queries every 50ms.

`Set-up ADB on Windows ?`
A quick Google search should help you out.
[Set Up Android ADB On Windows](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-set-up-android-adb-and-fastboot-on-windows-tutorial/)

---

To make proper use of Dumpsys,
See [What's the Android ADB shell "dumpsys" tool and what are its benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/whats-the-android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool-and-what-are-its-benefits?answertab=votes#tab-top)
http://android-test-tw.blogspot.in/2012/10/dumpsys-information-android-open-source.html

Getprop : [Android ADB commands to get the device properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099301/android-adb-commands-to-get-the-device-properties)

I hope this should give you a good start.