# How do I know which variant of Firefox OS is on my phone?

Tags: adb, firefox-os

I want to run [UI tests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Automated_testing/gaia-ui-tests) on my Firefox OS phone. [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/Builds) says I can't have a user build. So, how do I know which one I already have installed on my phone?

I already know how to enter ADB Shell.

Comment: This post is a part of my Self-Learner exercise. I thought it could save someone some time. That means I already have an answer. And I've already posted it. But please feel free to correct me if I've missed something, or add an answer if you know another way how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogous to Android ADB Shell, there's the [getprop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099301/android-adb-commands-to-get-the-device-properties) command. You just ask it for the variant, like this `adb shell getprop variant`.